# My App No Longer Prompts for Mic or Screen Recording Permissions

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-catalina

I am a beginning Swift developer who inherited a macOS app that does screen and microphone recording.

At one point this app would prompt a new user to grant Microphone and Screen Recording permissions as soon as those activities were initiated. I received reports that a new version that I built was not prompting for microphone permissions. I did some testing on my own system and now am having those same issues where audio and screen recording activities do not prompt for screen recording.

I have tried various combinations of the tccutil command to reset individual and all existing permissions. I've deleted and reinstalled the app numerous times and, I've rebooted numerous times and even cleared SMC but nothing seems to help.

Here is a snippet of code that I am using to start audio recording:

```
let settings = [
          AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
          AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
          AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.min.rawValue
        ]
         
        _recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: settings)
       _recorder?.record()
```

And here is the code used to take a screen shot of a window:

```
   static func generate(forWindow window: [String: AnyObject], mask windowMask: Bool) -> (image: CGImage?, window: CGRect)? {
    let windowId = (window[kCGWindowNumber as String] as! NSNumber).int32Value
    let rect = windowRect(forWindow: window)
     
    let option = windowMask ? CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .optionIncludingWindow) : CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: [.optionIncludingWindow, .optionOnScreenAboveWindow])
    var image = CGWindowListCreateImage(rect, option, CGWindowID(windowId), .nominalResolution)
     
    if image != nil {
      image = resize(image!)
    }
     
    return (image, rect)
  }
```

I am building with Xcode 12.3 and using Swift 4 -- I am not able to upgrade to Swift 5 at this point -- and am using Catalina 10.15.7.

As mentioned, I am new to Swift development and have exhausted all of my options. Is there any additional information that I can provide to help get this resolved?

Comment: Have you put usage descriptions in Info.plist? Such as [NSMicrophoneUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsmicrophoneusagedescription). Separately, does an older build of the app still prompt for permissions correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have Privacy - Microphone Usage Description set in Info.plist. The prior version of the app _did_ prompt for both mic and screen recording however, it no longer prompts for screen recording when I attempt to run it again. Seems as though something in the latest built version broke something that is preventing the prompt.

Comment: What if you change the app’s bundle ID?

Comment: @jtbandes great suggestion. I just tried that but have the same results. I know that Screen Recording permissions are working because Zoom prompted me for them again after I'd cleared everything out with the tccutil cmd.

Comment: Strange. You might have better luck posting on Apple's developer forums, which are frequented by employees. If necessary you can also use a [technical support incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/).